# Youtube Scraper c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

So I want to grab all links inside of this following link on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U

So this is what i've tried in c# win form selenium firefox drivers

```
IList<string> all = new List<string>();
foreach (IWebElement element in driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("vm-video-list")))
{
     all.Add( element.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).GetAttribute("href").ToString());
}
File.WriteAllLines("GrabbedLinks.txt", all);
```

So no errors show up but it only grabs one of the links... Instead of all 30 displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the elements having `vm-video-list` class, but you need to iterate over the links inside the `ol` list with `vm-video-list` class:

```
foreach (IWebElement link in driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("ol.vm-video-list a.vm-video-title-content")))
{
    all.Add(link).GetAttribute("href").ToString());
}
```